# How to Get Total number of streets from Google Map , from given area by using KML

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I want to find `total number` of `streets` from highlighted area on `google Map`, i'm `drawing polygon` by using `KML` file on `map`. and also want to find `total length` of all streets if possible.

Comment: I think you can do it with the help of another API, so if you want to find the no. of streets in a certain area, then I think you need Nearby Search in Places API. A [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for. For the length of street, you can use [Directions API or Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/) if you know the start and end points of a street

Comment: Yes @KENdi for nearby places we have to provide center point (Latlng) & Radius, but in my case, I have only boundary points, and area is not in fixed shape. So, it is not possible with Nearby Search places API.